# User-friendly nested routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am a ruby/rails newbie and have a belongs_to relationship between, let's say, group and user (user belongs_to group).

I would like to have the following type of url:

www.mysite.com/abcd/user/1  - (NOTE "group" is not part of the URL)

where abcd is the group name and 1 is the user ID.
Is this easy to do? How do I go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but try this:

```
scope :path => '/:group_name' do
  resources :users
end
```

You must find your group by `params[:group_name]` if you use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very easy to do in both Rails 2 and 3.

Assuming you're using Rails 3, you would do it like this

```
match ":group/user/:id", :to => "group#user"
```

When you use the match method, URL parts with a preceding colon will become parameters, so in your controller you would have params[:group] and params[:id] available. The :to paramater defines the controller and the action, so in this example it would send the request to the GroupController and the user action. :to can actually point to any Rack application end point, the "cont#action" is just a shorthand.

If you are using resources, you can set those up as normal, and then just define this non-standard route somewhere else in the stack and both will work side-by-side.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I should have specified but I am using rails 2.3.

Comment: will this work for 2.3? Also, I would like user_path(@user) to generate this path, will it work automatically?